# unused argument when doing descriptive stats on R

Tags: r

I keep getting the error unused argument for my by function , do I need to download a package I already have dplyr ,plyr,tidyr, data.table and pacman... need help thanks

```
DHB<- TA[, .(mean= mean(sum_tbret, na.rm = TRUE),
                  sd= sd(sum_tbret, na.rm = TRUE),
                  var= var(sum_tbret, na.rm=TRUE),
                  median= as.double(median(sum_tbret, na.rm = TRUE)),  ####Median has problems with data.table so need to tell it to convert to double
                  lq= quantile(sum_tbret, 0.25, na.rm = TRUE),
                  uq= quantile(sum_tbret, 0.75, na.rm = TRUE)),
              by =  "dhb2015"]
```

```
Error in `[.data.frame`(TA, , .(mean = mean(sum_tbret, na.rm = TRUE),  : 
  unused argument (by = "lb2018")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the error, it is still a `data.frame`, we can convert to `data.table` with `setDT` - converts in place (or `as.data.table`) and then the data.table method would work

```
library(data.table)
setDT(TA)[, .(mean= mean(sum_tbret, na.rm = TRUE),
              sd= sd(sum_tbret, na.rm = TRUE),
              var= var(sum_tbret, na.rm=TRUE),
              median= as.double(median(sum_tbret, na.rm = TRUE)),  
              lq= quantile(sum_tbret, 0.25, na.rm = TRUE),
              uq= quantile(sum_tbret, 0.75, na.rm = TRUE)),
          by =  dhb2015]
```